# How can I define an undefined method named "handleRequest" of class in Symfony 4?

Tags: forms, symfony, oop

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;

public function form($slug, Request $request){
  $id = $request->request->get('id');
  $EntityName = 'App\\Entity\\' . ucwords($slug);
  $item = new $EntityName();
  $item= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($EntityName)->find($id);
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($item);

  foreach ($classes->fieldMappings as $fieldMapping) {
    $form = $form->add($fieldMapping['fieldName'], TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')));
  }
  $form->add('cancel', ButtonType::class, array('label' => 'Abbrechen','attr' => array('class' => 'cancel form-btn btn btn-default pull-right close_sidebar close_h')))
  ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Speichern','attr' => array('id' => 'submit-my-beautiful-form','class' => 'form-btn btn btn-info pull-right','style' => 'margin-right:5px')))
  ->getForm();

  $form->handleRequest($request);
}
```

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "handleRequest" of class
>   "Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the method on the wrong object here. Note that you're calling `$this->createFormBuilder()` which returns a [`FormBuilder`](https://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.html), not a form.

What I would suggest is name the variable like this:

```
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($item);
```

And then, you're not storing the result of the `getForm()` call on the form builder. You should do this:

```
foreach (...) {
  $formBuilder->add(...);
}

$formBuilder
  ->add(...)
  ->add(...)

$form = $formBuilder->getForm();
```

...and this way you'll get an instance of `Form` which has the `handleRequest()` method, and the call to it will produce the result you're expecting.

Comment: P.S. Also note that you're overriding the `$item` var on line 4 of your method. This could probably be a bug.

Comment: I updated my code as you suggested: https://textuploader.com/d2bzn But it is the same error message

Comment: If I write the code for example static then everything works fine https://textuploader.com/d2bz8

Comment: Use the `getForm()` method to get the form instance. E.g. first add your fields via the builder, and then call `$form = $formBuilder->getForm()`

Comment: Yeah, the second implementation you've linked to should be correct.

Comment: No, no, the second one is static. I cannot use a static variation, because I have so many entities, I would need to write each one manually. I need the foreach loop variation

Comment: Your suggestion above leaded to the working solution: https://textuploader.com/d2b20 !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179447/discussion-between-kix-and-jarla).